# How to access the original Entity used when repository.save(entity) is invoked from Hibernate AbstractEvents and EventListeners?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I am using JPA/Hibernate/Spring and have a simple JPA Entity model as shown here :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "record")
public class Record extends BaseEntity {
  
  //...
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Document> documents;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class Document extends BaseEntity {

//...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "record_id")
private Record record;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "document_model_id")
private DocumentModel documentModel;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document_model")
public class DocumentModel extends BaseEntity {
//...
}
```

and my `RecordService` as shown here:

```
@Transactional
public class RecordService {

private RecordRepository repository;     

  public RecordDTO update(RecordDTO dto) {
    Record record = repository.findById(dto.getId()); 
    updateEntity(entity, dto);
    repository.save(entity); 
  }
}
```

---

I also have a generic event listener:

```
public class RecordEventListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {
   
   @Override
   public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

     Object[] oldState = event.getOldState();
     Object[] currentState = event.getState();
     Object entity = event.getEntity();
     //original Record id? 
   }

   //...
}
```

My understanding is that when I invoke the update method (on the service layer) any JPA object that is dirty will be updated/persisted in the database and before closing the transaction will generate the PostUpdate event to be handled by the listener. At times there is no direct change on the Record object itself and hence there wont be a produced PostUpdateEvent for the Record entity itself but only for other affected JPA entities on the Record object graph, which is expected.

Is it possible to somehow get hold of the original object that triggered the saving via the `repository.save(entity);` method call via the transaction info ? I need to somehow access its id.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "original id"? The id can't change, so it's the same for the "current entity" as it was for when the entity was passed to `save`. The `PostUpdateEvent` even has a `getId` method you can use for this purpose.

Comment: I mean the original id of the entity passed to `repository.save(entity); ` method. In other words i need to know the record id.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. The "record id" is the primary key I assume? This is what you can access through `PostUpdateEvent#getId()`

Comment: Let me try again. The Record JPA entity graph relates to Document and DocumentModel objects.  Let's assume that when I invoke the service method `updateEntity(entity, dto)` I actually update a DocumentModel object that is found on the Record object graph. When I then save using the Record service method `repository.save(entity)` and before the transaction closes there will be **only one PostUpdateEvent for the DocumentModel update** even though I invoked the `repository.save(entity)` passing in a record param. Is there a way to retrieve the id passed in the `repository.save(entity)` method?

Comment: Oh, so you want the id of the "parent" entity. I don't think that is possible. You can put a field into your entity though that captures this reference and access that then.

Comment: Precisely that. Hmm not sure about having the recordId on every other JPA entity as a property or ensuring that each object has a property linking to its parent (and then traverse any jpa object graph until I reach the top = Record object). Also i thought about caching the transactionId -> recordId before I save a record and retrieve it from the listener, but could not find how to retrieve the transactionId from a @Transational method.